# Initialize Dictionary in Code Behind and access in view asp.net Webform

Tags: asp.net

I would like to just initialize a dictionary on page load then access this dictionary values in foreach loop. I first initialize dictionary then give its object to Viewstate to access in HTML but facing an error.

Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<object, object> mydictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    mydictionary["name"] = "Faizan";
    mydictionary["age"] = 10;
    ViewState["Data"] = mydictionary;

    //Session["FirstName"] = name;
}
```

Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Faizan._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table>
    <% foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in ViewState["Data"]) { %>
        <tr><td><%= myItem.title %></td></tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your `ViewState` as `Dictionary<object, object`> like this:

```
<table>
    <% foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in ViewState["w"] as Dictionary<object, object>)
        { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= pair.Key %> = <%=pair.Value%></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to the ViewState object with "w" key, but retrieving with "Data" key.

Also, ViewState is meant to store data for page request cycles - you don't need to add directly to view state, you can make a public pr protected property in your code behind and use that in your loop.

Alternately, you could also use a repeater, which would add the items in ViewState automatically so that they are persisted in postback cycles.

Comment: Ok Martin I have fixed this issue but still getting "foreach statement cannot operator on variable of type object"

Comment: ViewState items are Objects, you need to cast them to the correct type. Use a property or repeater as per my comment.